# Convert String into Variable in AngularJS like in PHP variable variables

Tags: angularjs

This is the outcome I am looking for:

```
$scope.donotShow = false;
```

The way I want to get it is in the controller in which I have one variable to work with:

```
var slug = "donot";
```

I would like to combine it with the string "Show":

```
var slugshow = slug + "Show";
```

From here I want the outcome I am looking for but this does not work:

```
$scope.slugshow = false;
```

How do I make the var slugshow show as "donotShow" thus giving me

```
$scope.donotShow = false;
```

Comment: `$scope[slug + 'Show'] = false;`

Comment: Hey Stewie, thank you so much I had tried everything under the sun and I even thought I tried what you had but evidently not.  Have a blessed day.